# Cron is not Working in Alfresco

Tags: lucene, cron, alfresco

I have written a cron to run every 30 minutes in scheduled-action-services-context.xml file

However I see that it is not working, when I check the log I can find only this error.

For my cron, I have also used lucene search. So I beleive this error is regarding that, so kindly help me in fixing it. Here is the error:

```
ERROR [quartz.core.JobRunShell] [DefaultScheduler_Worker-8] Job jobGroup.jobD threw an unhandled Exception: 
 org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.lucene.LuceneQueryParserException: 03020086
```

Answer (score 1):

The error log you show is most likely the reason behind your scheduled action not properly working. In facts, it seems that the action is properly scheduled, but it then fails to complete as you provided an invalid Lucene query. Without the query itself or any other detail such as the relevant Spring config or action implementation details, I can only tell you to:

- double check the lucene query
- verify that that error log appears precisely when you would expect your action to be scheduled